# How to interpolate colors on scattered points for a smooth visualization

Tags: graphics, color

I am a novice user, so please bear with me! I have a set of random points which are color-coded by some function. The point distribution is fairly dense so I should be able to see a smooth color distribution, but I see "choppy" discrete points. I use the following for processing:

```
g0 = Graphics[{PointSize @ .003, Opacity[0.075], Point[pts, VertexColors -> vc]}];
```

where `pts` is an array of 2D points (with (x,y) coordinates) and `vc` is some functional distribution of colors. The choice of `PointSize` essentially allows me to cover up the spaces that separate the points -- when `PointSize` is too small, one sees dots on a blank background, but when `PointSize` is too large, one sees an ugly, choppy color distribution, although the space separating the points is now covered.

I use `Opacity` to smooth out the choppiness, and for the most part it works. However, I would like to have a more elegant/exact control of this process. I would like to apply a radially symmetric filter function of sorts to these data points such that the color value at the center of each element of `pts` is `vc` and drops to some value (say, zero) at the edge of the radius of size `PointSize`. For the sake of argument let's just say the filter function at each point is `vc * Max[0 , 1 - Abs[r/0.003 ]]`, where `0 <= r <= 0.003`. This filter function should interpolate the colors in between points smoothly and provide a nicer looking field (it will look as if the points were first projected onto a uniform grid and then displayed smoothly).

Note that processing speed is somewhat important because I'm visualizing unsteady field of hundreds of thousands of points per timestep

Hopefully I'm clear enough with my request.

I'm including a side-by-side image: Left uses PointSize @ .005 (exaggerated to make my point); Right uses PointSize @ .005 and Opacity[0.07]. The problem with Opacity is loss of sharpness.

[image]

The "data" is at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzCeMgfPKi0vd0dCT2lRWTEzd0E/view?usp=sharing

The code snippet to extract the correct "data" and plot it with a color scheme that's close enough to my own is given below (setting Opacity to 1 shows the choppy version):

```
cf = ColorData["LightTemperatureMap"];
dat = Transpose[Import["data", "Table", "HeaderLines" -> 1]];
pts = Transpose[{dat[[1]], dat[[2]]}];
vc = cf /@ Rescale[Clip[-dat[[4]], {-50, 50}]];
g0 = Graphics[{PointSize@.003, Opacity[0.1], Point[pts, VertexColors -> vc]},
         Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{-.35, 2.15}, {-.8, .8}}, ImageSize -> {1200}];
Show[g0]
```

Comment: Sample data would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ C. E. I'm adding the link to the data, as well as the code snippet, to my original question

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps an acceptable solution is to convert your plot to an image and apply very light filtering on it. At least to my eye, a median filter seems fit the bill here: it retains as much sharpness as possible, while "blending points" to form more uniform swaths

Using your data (notice that I removed your `PlotRange` option from `Graphics` for convenience in posting the pictures here, but it has no effect on the image generation):

```
g0 = Graphics[
   {PointSize@.003, Point[pts, VertexColors -> vc]},
   Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 1200
   ];
img = Image@%;
GraphicsRow[{img, MedianFilter[img, 4]}, ImageSize -> Full]
```

Below are the results. Your original `Graphics` object is on the left; the filtered image on the right (click on the image to open a larger version for better viewing).

[image: two figures linked]

Here is a zoomed-in detail of the filtered image. If you need higher-resolution results, you can increase `ImageSize` within `Graphics` before rasterization by `Image`.

[image: zoomed in]

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work well. I've replaced the data file with a new one, representing the flow at a later time. The post-processed filtering approach is still spotty, or too smeared out if one uses a larger value for MedianFilter. The best approach would be to apply the "filter" to the points themselves. The "filter" acts like a Radial Basis Function (RBF) for interpolation, so the color values from neighboring points superimpose linearly to give a new color value (hence leading to a smooth color distribution). Opacity[] essentially behaves as a piecewise-constant RBF.